# How to create custom textbox component in Angular 9

Tags: angular, typescript, components

I want to create some common components for HTML tags in Angular 9, like text-box.

**Parent Component HTML:**

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
            <textbox [name]="'articleDto.articleName'" (changeEvent)="txtChange($event)" [label]="'Article Name'" [placeholder]="'Article Name'"></textbox>
            <textbox [name]="'articleDto.titleName'" [label]="'Title Name'" [placeholder]="'Title Name'"></textbox>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success mr-2">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**Parent Component TS Code:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { spinx } from '../core/lib/spinx.service';
import Swal from 'sweetalert2';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-new-article',
  templateUrl: './new-article.component.html'
})
export class NewArticleComponent implements OnInit {

  articleDto:any = {};
  constructor(private spinxService: spinx) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  txtChange(event){
    alert(this.articleDto.articleName)
  }
}
```

**Child Component TS:**

```
import { Component, forwardRef, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
  selector: 'textbox',
  template: `
  <div class="form-group">
  <label>{{label}}</label>
  <input type="text" name="{{name}}" [(ngModel)]="{{name}}" (change)="changeComplete()" class="form-control" placeholder="{{placeholder}}">
  </div>
  `,
  providers: [
    {provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, useExisting: TextboxComponent, multi: true}
  ]
})
export class TextboxComponent  {
  @Input() placeholder: string;
  @Input() name: string;
  @Input() label: string;
  @Output()
  changeEvent = new EventEmitter<string>();
  changeComplete() {
    this.changeEvent.emit('complete');
  }
}
```

I'm not able to use **`[(ngModel)]="{{name}}"`** in child component which is mapped with the parent Component.

Please provide a solution/suggestion for this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While doing two way data binding with ngModel, the appropriate syntax is :

```
 [(ngModel)]="name"
```

Interpolation need not be used with the variable name.

Update : 
 1. If the components have a parent/child relationship, as in your case, You can share data between them via @Input() and @Output() decorators.

Sharing data from Parent to Child using @Input() :

```
<h3>Parent Component</h3>

<label>Parent Component</label>c
<input type="number" [(ngModel)]='parentValue'/>

<p>Value of child component is: </p>
<app-child [value]='parentValue'></app-child>
```

And in the child component, the 'parentValue' can be received as :

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css']
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() value: number;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Now, in the case of sending data from Child to Parent, we can use an @Output() event emitter. So the parent would have a function to receive the emitted data from child as :

```
parent-app.component.html 
    <app-child [value]="parentValue" (childEvent)="childEvent($event)"></app-child>

parent-app.component.ts

childEvent(event) {
console.log(event);
}

And, the child.component.ts would look like :

import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css']
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() PData: number;
  @Output() childEvent = new EventEmitter();
  constructor() { }
  onChange(value) {
    this.childEvent.emit(value);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Comment: Dear Gauri it gives me just my model name that is articleDto.articleName  but i want the value in parent component object they write some text in child component textbox.